# VBA code for sumifs function

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and I get run-time error '1004'  is it to do with text as the variables?  Ive tried also refering to the cells that contain my condition directly but have the same problem

```
Sub sumifs()
Dim Month_tally As Double
Dim Monthrange As Range

Set Monthrange = Range("B2:D5")
Set months = Range("B1:D1")
Set Prospects = Range("A2:A4")

Range("B6").Formula = WorksheetFunction.sumifs(Monthrange, months, (May), Prospects, (CN))

End Sub


May June    July
```

CN  456 2   2
Nj  2   2   2
BH  2   456 5647
BG  4567    2   2

Comment: what's `(May)` and `(CN)`? If they are text just double-quote them instead of brackets like `WorksheetFunction.sumifs(Monthrange, months, "May", Prospects, "CN")`

Comment: yes they are just text, however, I had tried the double quotation as well and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your user defined function may be named ending with 's' but the Excel worksheet function is simply 'sumif' and takes just 3 parameters: range, criteria, sum_range.  Perhaps you're actually trying to do this:

```
Range("B6").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(  OFFSET( R[-4]C[-1], 0, MATCH(""May"", R[-5]C:R[-5]C[2], FALSE), 4, 1 )  )"
```

EDIT

OK, try this instead:

```
Sub sumifs()
    'Dim Month_tally As Double
    Dim Monthrange As Range
    Dim Months As Range
    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set Monthrange = Range("A1:D5")   'Include the first column and header row
    Set Months = Range("B1:D1")
    Set CriteriaRange = Range("A10:A11")
    'Set Prospects = Range("A2:A4")

    Range("A1").Value = "Prospects"   ' just to ensure first column has header

    Range("A10").Value = "Prospects"
    Range("A11").Value = "CN"
    Range("B10").Value = "Column to sum"
    Range("B11").Value = "May"

    Range("B6").Value = WorksheetFunction.DSum(Monthrange, Range("B11"), CriteriaRange)

End Sub
```

Of course, it becomes trivial via a Pivot Table.  Can you get the source data structured as 3 columns: Prospects, Month, ProdQty?

Comment: Hi there are two functions one is sumif, where you sum on one variable and another sumifs where you can sum on a number of variables.  What I am trying to achieve is summing on two variables.  I want to know the production in a month in each prospect.  I have been wondering if the problems is alos related to the way the data is store. The months are stored in the table horizontally but the prospects are stored vertically in the table

Comment: Did the revision fix your problem @user3614197?

Comment: HI thanks help, when I looked at the code i though it was going to work, however, it tally incorrectly and puts "may" and "CN" and "prospect" into cells where I dont want.  I'm going to park this for a while and come back.  I have manged to get the results I want in a different way but not the way I had wanted to do it

Answer (score 0):

just remove the "s" at end of `WorksheetFunction.sumifs` and use the correct syntax.